# leverage mypy to annotate variables and return value

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

A common function to get nested json object safely.

```
def safe_get(dct, keys):
for key in keys.split("."):
    try:
        dct = dct[key]
    except:
        return None
return dct
```

Leverage mypy to check type, like below.

```
    def safe_get(dct: dict, keys: str) -> Union[str,int,bool,None]:
    for key in keys.split("."):
        try:
            dct = dct[key]
        except:
            return None
    return dct
```

However, when I run `python3 -m mypy --follow-imports=silent --python-version ${PYTHON_VERSION} --strict --implicit-reexport ${SOURCES[@]}` in `strict` mode. It prompts me

```
chalicelib/fly.py:31: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:37: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[Any, Any]", expected "Union[str, bool, int, None]")
chalicelib/fly.py:40: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:41: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[str, int, None]", expected "str")
chalicelib/fly.py:44: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:45: error: Item "bool" of "Union[str, bool, int, None]" has no attribute "split"
chalicelib/fly.py:45: error: Item "int" of "Union[str, bool, int, None]" has no attribute "split"
chalicelib/fly.py:45: error: Item "None" of "Union[str, bool, int, None]" has no attribute "split"
chalicelib/fly.py:48: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:49: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[str, int, None]", expected "str")
chalicelib/fly.py:52: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:53: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[str, int]", expected "str")
chalicelib/fly.py:56: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:57: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[str, int]", expected "str")
chalicelib/fly.py:60: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:61: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[str, int, None]", expected "str")
chalicelib/fly.py:64: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
chalicelib/fly.py:66: error: Item "str" of "Union[str, bool, int, None]" has no attribute "items"
chalicelib/fly.py:66: error: Item "bool" of "Union[str, bool, int, None]" has no attribute "items"
chalicelib/fly.py:66: error: Item "int" of "Union[str, bool, int, None]" has no attribute "items"
chalicelib/fly.py:66: error: Item "None" of "Union[str, bool, int, None]" has no attribute "items"
chalicelib/fly.py:78: error: Implicit generic "Any". Use "typing.Dict" and specify generic parameters
Found 23 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

wherever `safe_get` triggered, it may return `str`, `int`, `bool` or `None`. So I use typing.Union to aggregate all possible types there. However, it seems that it doesn't making sense to `mypy`. Anybody can suggest how to annotate the return value in this case?
Besides, plz find configuration of mypy below.

```
[mypy]
python_version = 3.8
warn_unused_configs = True

[mypy-boto3.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-botocore.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True

[mypy-kubernetes.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got to go with an `Any` type in the input, since cyclic type definitions are tricky:

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Union

def safe_get(dct: Dict[str, Any], keys: str) -> Union[str, int, bool, None]:
    d: Any = dct
    for key in keys.split("."):
        try:
            d = d[key]
        except KeyError:
            return None
    if isinstance(d, str) or isinstance(d, int) or isinstance(d, bool):
        return d
    return None
```